What is the difference between std::span and gsl::span?
Last decade, when std::span was not standardized, the C++ Core Guidelines project got started. It quickly developed a small library of constructs which authors found they need to recommend in order to be able to abide by the guidelines - the guidelines support library (GSL) (link is to Microsoft's implementation). Among other things, the GSL includes a span class: gsl::span<T>. Eventually, in 2020, std::span was officially standardized.
Recently, as I mentioned std::span to someone, they told me:

std::span is a trap, gsl::span should be used instead

what could they have meant? Isn't std::span supposed to be basically the same thing as gsl::span? I mean,  after all, it's just a structure with a pointer and a size_t, isn't it?

From the GSL span class' documentation page (emphasis mine):

The only difference between gsl::span and std::span is that
gsl::span strictly enforces runtime bounds checking. Any violations
of the bounds check results in termination of the program.

and the same goes for the two span classes' iterators.

The std::span abides by the P2137 goals and principles of C++.  (Note: P2137 is not (nor will ever be) an approved proposal.  It's unofficial.)  The gsl::span "fat pointer" is not constrained to P2137, and biases towards safety at the cost of performance.  (I'm strongly in favor of safety for C++, and I wish the language would allow for explicit safety opt-out in critical sections rather than no safety anywhere all the time.)

@Eljay Its tough, C++ is all about "don't pay for what you don't use" as primary principle. But then it also gets a lot of pushback becuase it is not a "safe/secure" language. So from that point of view an opt-in would also make sense, but it should be an opt-in at a global level (conditional compilation?)

@PepijnKramer • Aye.  I have a keen interest in Herb Sutter's C++ syntax 2 experiment, and Sean Baxter's Circle and New Circle experiments.  I don't think the other "C++ successor languages" efforts like Carruth's Carbon or Abraham's Hylo will take the mantle from C++.  (Although best of luck to those efforts, and I wish them all the success.  Just that D has proven that a "better C++ than C++" isn't going to win the hearts-and-minds.)

I like Herb's approach a lot (analyse and make weighted choices). And think he's really working with Bjarne's ideas too : "in C++ there is a simpler language waiting to get out".
And somehow it reminds me of the C++ frontend for "C" approach (which got me started with C++ back in '94). Too bad this isn't a place for long discussions ;)
Would be nice to get "compilation profiles" where you could switch on and off parts of C++ (like switching of implicit conversions, nodiscard returns by default etc)

I don't think it's accurate to suggest that std::span abides by P2137 due to its standardization. That paper was a suggestion that famously didn't get consensus.
